# What do we do with existing questions about the Ubuntu Development Release on or after the final release date?

Tags: discussion, review

Come the release of the development release of Ubuntu, there will be lots of existing questions about the Ubuntu development release that were off topic for several good reasons, including the fact that unofficial bugs (including with the installer) and other unknowns and uncertainties haven't been dealt with yet.

After said release date, should we close the questions that were created before the release date of whichever Ubuntu version the questions are about?

Comment: If they are closed, leave them closed.

Answer (score 3):

That depends. If the question is reusable, say:

- [What has Jockey been replaced with in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441415/what-has-jockey-been-replaced-with-in-14-04)

Then yes. You can usually edit it to "future proof it". If the question makes no sense anymore, vote to close.

Comment: Edited to be "future proof".